# Vue.js Dynamic Component is no Created but showing in Console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my SimpleFlowchart.vue **ChildComponent**

```
 <FlowchartDecision v-bind.sync="decision" 
      v-for="(decision, index) in scene.decisions" 
      :key="`decision${index}`"
      :options="nodeOptions">
    </FlowchartDecision>
```

This is how i am returning it in Props

```
Props:{
     scene:{
      decisions: [
            {
              id: '',
               x: '',
               y: '',
               type: '',
               label: '',
              }
            ],
       decisions:[],
    }
}
```

This is my adddecision function method

```
 adddecision(y,nid,x){
    this.scene.decisions.push({
          id: '',
          x: '',
          y: '',
          type: '',
          label: '',
      })
     console.log(this.scene.decisions);
}
```

This is my Parent Component

here i am doing this

```
 <button  @click="adddecision()">+</button>
```

This is how i am Emitting this in ParentComponent which is FlowchartDecision.vue

```
   adddecision(){
    this.$emit('adddecision')
  },
```

I am only Calling this SimpleFlowchart.vue Component in App.vue
   Here i have passed decisions as a prop in scene

```
       decisions:[
   {
      id:10,
      x:-1000,
      y:170,
      type:'asad',
      label:'bilal'
   }
 ],
```

Here is the Output which i am getting in the Console this is the prop that i have passed in app.vue which i am getting in console

This is my Console output which i have passed in app.vue prop
Please Click on the following link to open the image

https://gyazo.com/c54b1713bdf32a1aef9d90a994f825c7

Comment: It would be way easier to help you if you could recreate your problem with e.g. https://codesandbox.io/
For me, I am not quite sure which component has which function and what exactly is not working. Have you installed Vue devtools? Does your `adddecision` function work, e.g. is the array length increased?

Comment: Yes the array length is increasing

Comment: The Array Length is increasing Brother here is the Link for that i will be Very helpfull if you help me with this @Matthias
https://gyazo.com/dd68ef88b57a162c73be25a29d510708?token=141f6bbf8499ab53abdb8cc12dbe3fd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that i was not Binding it with flowchartdecision component when i bind it works fine and i was calling it inself another component thats why it was not working fine

Answer (score 0):

Please try using deepCopy to change reference:

```
adddecision(y,nid,x){
   this.scene.decisions.push({
         id: '',
         x: '',
         y: '',
         type: '',
         label: '',
     })
   this.scene = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.scene))
}
```

Comment: the Problem was that i was not passing binding it with flowchartdecision component